# Calling .dll functions of embedded Qt

Tags: python, c++, qt, dll

There is a software Siemens NX. In this software I can use Python for developing some plugins and applications for this software via NXOpen API. It also has an embedded Python interpreter.

I've also found some Qt libraries in the installed NX directory. There are some files like Qt5GuiNX.dll, Qt5CoreNX.dll etc. So I suppose NX uses this files for its internal plugins.

I wanna use these libraries to developing some user intafaces in my plugins. The reason is simple: Each plugin hav to be installed on the users' machines. I would like to avoid installing additional frameworks and libraries on them.

I want to use these libraries for developing user interface in my plugins. So I tried to use SIP, but it uses .sip files for C++ functions/classes wrappers. Each .sip file contains .h file of certain Qt library which I don't have. So I can't use SIP for binding .dll as I understood.

I suppose I can use ctypes module. But when I try to call some functions I see following:

[image]

And this library has got a lot of C++ functions and few C ones:

[image]

Do you have any ideas how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the Qt libraries are not supposed to be used by developers.

To develop user interfaces in NX, you usually use the tool called "Block UI Styler", which you can find in the ribbon tab `Application -> More -> Block UI Styler`.

In the "Block UI Styler" you can create your user interfaces, and export them with an initial code file.

Another approach is to use the general C++ headers or the managed libraries, and create a windows form.

Edit: Note that the generated UI file have to be in your `application` config directory.